# “AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'arma_order_select_ic'” when trying to run IPython script vs Python script

Tags: python, import, module, ipython

I am trying to import a module from statsmodels, now I have a problem, when I import the file by

```
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import arma_order_select_ic
```

I get

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-6e5ef3c63065> in <module>()
----> 1 from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import arma_order_select_ic

ImportError: cannot import name arma_order_select_ic
```

However, when I do this in my computer installed python it works fine. What is going wrong? I know that this might be due to the paths of each Ipython and Python. However, since I am new may anyone give me a detailed answer why this is happening and help me to make my it easy to import modules in Ipython.

Comment: do without the `asi.`. You have imported `arma_order_select_ic`, not `asi`.

Comment: I tried it did not work

Comment: Check `sys.executable` and `sys.path` in both cases. Most likely IPython is running on a different Python installation.

Answer (score 0):

As Thomas have pointed out in the comment. I have Check sys.executable and sys.path as follow

```
import sys
sys.executable
sys.path
```

It seems that it was different the one I had in Ipython is different from the one I have on my installed Python. Therefore, different results. Moreover, I was running my IPython on https://www.wakari.io/wakari which is different from Jupyter. Therefore, I had to run my Python code in Jupter (the new Ipython kind) where things work best.

Thanks to Thomas for making me see this..